# Laravel 5.7 Undefined variable in view

Tags: php, laravel

I follow the guide ( https://www.phpflow.com/php/laravel-5-6-crud-operation-using-resource-controller/ ) and at point "How To Create Listing in Laravel 5.6" I get the error::

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Undefined variable: employees (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)

Previous exceptions
* Undefined variable: employees (0)

And in code window the error is:

```
<?php 
$__currentLoopData = $employees;
$__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData);
foreach($__currentLoopData as $key => $emp): 
    $__env->incrementLoopIndices();
    $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

Is it a compatibility issue between 5.6 and 5.7 or what? (please note that I am a noob in Laravel)

Comment: Can you please show your controller code?

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward, `$employees` is missing. Make sure you passed it through to your view. And that you don't have a typo, `'employee' => $employees`

Comment: Are you passing the employee variable to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide is pretty slim, what you need to do in order to get you index working:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Employee;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        return view('pages.index', ['employees' => Employee::all()]);
    }

    // ... The rest of the controller method below
}
```

If your resource definition is:

```
Route::resource('employee', 'EmployeeController');
```

The **Path (URL)** to access this will be: `/employee`

Answer (score 1):

According to your link I do not see the full code of the controller, but your `index` method should look like this

```
public function index()
{
    $employees = Employee::all();

    // Pass data to view
    return view('employee.index', ['employees' => $employees]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error remains, part of my code so far, EmployeeController.php:

```
public function index()
{
$employees = Employee::all();
return view('employee.index', ['employees' => $employees]);
}
```

Employee.php

```
class Employee extends Model
{
// Table name
protected $table = 'crud';
// Primary key
public $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

index.blade.php

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($employees as $key => $emp)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $emp->id }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: You should be returning `pages.index` not `employee.index`

Comment: You are correct, I changed it to `pages.index` but the error remains the same. I also tried `return view('pages.index')->with('employees', $employees);`, but nothing changed.

Comment: try clearing your cached views. Also, what does your route look like? And what url are you accessing in your browser?

Comment: When I delete the code between `<tbody></tbody>`  tags then the page loads fine. The web.php has 2 lines of code `Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::resource('employee', 'EmployeeController');` .

Comment: And what url are you hitting in your browser?

Comment: modified localhost `crud.dev`

Comment: Nothing, that is it. The error shows a correct path `"Undefined variable: employees (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)"`

Comment: this path gives me `"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'crud.crud' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `crud`)"`

Comment: Thats because that table doesn't exist in your database, your model table definition is: `protected $table = 'crud';`

Comment: I changed the table name in Employee.php to 'employee' and got rid of the error. Always the small and dumb thing. Thank you very much.